# dgrid selection- select row only when I click on check box

Tags: selection, dgrid

I have a dgrid with selection extention.
how can I be able to select any row without checking the box.
I mean, I can check to check box only if I click on it directly.

Answer (score 3):

The wording in your question's description sounds a little bit off from your question's title, but I *think* what you're asking is how to allow selecting rows only via a checkbox in a selector column.  You can do this with a combination of the `Selection` mixin with `selectionMode: 'none'` and a column using the `selector` column plugin.  Here's a rough example:

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dgrid/Grid',
    'dgrid/Selection',
    'dgrid/selector'
], function (declare, Grid, Selection, selector) {
    var SelectionGrid = declare([Grid, Selection]);
    var grid = new SelectionGrid({
        columns: {
            selector: selector({ label: '' }),
            // other columns here...
        },
        selectionMode: 'none'
    });
    // Place, startup the grid, and add data here...
});
```

You can see examples like this in dgrid's `test/selector.html` page.

Comment: thanks for the great answer ken.
the none mode really  solves the issue.
another issue that occurred is that after I changed the grid cellNavigation to false,the grid stopped focusing the clicked cell but it focuses the whole row. why is that?

Comment: That is what setting `cellNavigation` to `false` does, by definition - it changes the behavior of the `Keyboard` mixin so that it focuses at row level rather than cell level.  You could similarly apply selections at the row level by mixing in just `Selection` rather than `CellSelection` (and that's usually more appropriate for cases with `selector` anyway).

Comment: the idea behind setting cellNavigation to false so I can use select widgets in the header (which made by 'renderHeaderCell'), because when I am on a false mode, it doesn't open the dropdown.
just when I am on a true cellNavigation it opens.
using the cellSelection doesn't allow that too.